# How to use more connections using Alamofire

Tags: macos, swift, alamofire

Alamofire is great. I use it on OS X to download a bunch (over 500) html files simultaneously in just a few lines of Swift. However, my avg download rate during execution is about 700KB/s and my max download capacity on this network connection is 6MB/s. When I look at my Xcode debugger I see that only 5 TCP connections are established simultaneously during execution. Is there a way to configure Alamofire so that more simultaneous connections are established so that more of my download bandwidth is used and downloads complete quicker? Thanks!

Comment: This max number of concurrent connections is dictated by the OS, not by Alamofire.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I'll do some research on how to adjust these settings in the OS

Comment: I don't believe you can. There is a `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost` property on the session configuration, so you can try that, but you may be limited.

Comment: Thanks Rob! That was it, per the documentation the default number for OS X is 6, and I just set it to 24 and I got over 2 MB/s of performance. I'll continue to tweak to maximize performance

Answer (score 0):

Per Rob's comment, the answer is to set HTTPMaximumConnectionPerHost to higher than the default, which for OS X is 6. I've tripled performance setting it to 24.